# Best way to move between nested items in sibling nodes?

Tags: xml, xslt, tei

I have a problem that I'm sure is actually fairly simple to answer, but I can't figure it out and my attempt to ask about it before was unduly complex.

I have a page that is being generated from TEI XML that has some text associated with an image file:

```
<sourceDoc xml:id="textContent">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="West Wall">
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.60">
            <label>Verse 60</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.63">
            <label>Verse 63</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_2.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.65">
            <label>Verse 65</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_3.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.66">
            <label>Verse 66</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_4.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.68">
            <label>Verse 68</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_5.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.69">
            <label>Verse 69</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_6.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</sourceDoc>
```

(I've removed the text from the example here to avoid extra cruft)

I generate a header at the top of my page based on thumbnail images of the image associated with each piece of text.  So `www_test_1-thumbnail.jpg`, etc.  Using the following xsl I can get the header to appear correctly (tei is the tei namespace, which can be declared at `xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"`):

```
<xsl:template match="tei:surface">
    <div id="centerMenu">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:graphic" mode="list"/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:graphic" mode="list">
    <span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
        <a class="nav_link">
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring(@url,1,string-length(@url)-4),'.html')"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <img class="thumbnail">
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="concat(substring(@url,1,string-length(@url)-4),'-thumbnail.jpg')"
                    />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                    <xsl:value-of select="../tei:label"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </img>
        </a>
    </span>
</xsl:template>
```

My problem is that there are times I need to jump from one `<surfaceGrp>`-wrapped set of elements to another. So if, for example, there was a "South Wall" `<surfaceGrp>` I need to be able to grab the url of that upcoming element so that I can jump to the next block of thumbnail images:

```
<sourceDoc xml:id="textContent">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="West Wall">
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.60">
            <label>Verse 60</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.63">
            <label>Verse 63</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_2.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.65">
            <label>Verse 65</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_3.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.66">
            <label>Verse 66</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_4.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.68">
            <label>Verse 68</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_5.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.69">
            <label>Verse 69</label>
            <graphic url="ww_test_6.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="wall" n="South Wall">
        <surface xml:id="EETS.QD.70">
            <label>Verse 70</label>
            <graphic url="sw_test_1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</sourceDoc>
```

Making things even more complex is that there are times that everything has to be wrapped in another `<surfaceGrp>` element because there's a larger block they're a part of. Which might look like this:

```
<sourceDoc xml:id="textContent">
<surfaceGrp xml:id="g.8" n="gathering">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="f.66" n="folio">
        <surface n="recto">
            <label>Verse 60</label>
            <graphic url="pageimage1.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface n="verso">
            <label>Verse 63</label>
            <graphic url="pageimage2.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="f.67" n="folio>
        <surface n="recto">
            <label>Verse 65</label>
            <graphic url="pageimage3.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface n="verso">
            <label>Verse 66</label>
            <graphic url="pageimage4.jpg"/>
        </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</surfaceGrp>
<surfaceGrp xml:id="g.9" n="gathering">
    <surfaceGrp xml:id="f.67" n="folio>
        <surface n="recto">
            <label>Verse 68</label>
            <graphic url="pageimage5.jpg"/>
        </surface>
        <surface n="verso">
            <label>Verse 69</label>
            <graphic url="pageimage6.jpg"/>
       </surface>
    </surfaceGrp>
</surfaceGrp>
</sourceDoc>
```

So my questions are twofold:

1. How do I get my xsl to display everything in the first `<surfaceGrp>` tree?  My current code will display the two surfaces for the child `<surfaceGrp>` but not everything.
2. How would I generate a link from Verse 66 to Verse 68 in my example above, and is it fundamentally different than a link from Verse 65 to Verse 66?  I can jump to the next item and the next `<surfaceGrp>` using some convoluted code I have, but it is an incredibly buggy solution and breaks entirely once the second `<surfaceGrp>` layer is added.  If there's a standard solution I'd appreciate  a nod in the right direction.

The html code that the xsl generates currently with the code I have is as follows:

```
<div id="centerMenu">
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_1.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_1-thumbnail.jpg" alt="First Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_2.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_2-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Second Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_3.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_3-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Third Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_4.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_4-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Fourth Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_5.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_5-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Fifth Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
<span class="menuitem" id="image_thumbnail">
    <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_6.html">
        <img class="thumbnail" src="../../Quis_Dabit/Clopton/Thumbnails/ww_test_6-thumbnail.jpg" alt="Sixth Panel" />
    </a>
</span>
</div>

<div id="rightMenu">
    <span class="menuitem" id="previousItem">
        <a class="nav_link">Previous</a>
    </span>
    <span class="menuitem" id="nextItem">
        <a class="nav_link" href="ww_test_2.html">Next</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: I understand you want to create HTML from your XML. Consider to post the HTML you want to create for the last XML input snippet in your question, currently it is not clear which HTML you want to create when you have nested `surfaceGrp` elements. Also in the previous sample you have `surfaceGrp xml:id="wall"` twice, an id should be unique. Do you want to group those elements together when they have the same id?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look.  I added the html I'd like to generate.  It works with the code I currently have (which doesn't work with the second surfaceGrp element.